# CSS parent element ignore the text within child element to determine width

Tags: html, css

Without fixing the widths of any of the elements, I would like the parent div element to ignore the text when setting it's width. I want the element's width only to be affected by the width of the image.

```
<div>
    <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/9BAW9uE48gxNUmnQ7T6ALpNTsrCHOZBMfF__mbamBC36edSw0uc-kjQxgtZ3O3aQWFY=h900"/>
    <p>I want this text to wrap once this paragraph element reaches the width of the image.</p>
</div>

div {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/y8Qnd/)

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change display property of div to `table-caption`
(Tested in firefox and chrome)

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Qnd/4/)

Comment: nice one, and support doesn't seem that bad eather (IE8+): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Honestly, I am happier than you can believe.

Comment: This is amazing! Spent a good chunk of time trying to hack this together till I found this ridiculously simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best that I've found:

http://jsfiddle.net/y8Qnd/3/

What I've done is to take the `p` tag out of flow with `position: absolute` so that the containing div has the width of just the image. Then, have the `p` tag inherit the width of its parent, the container. This does not fix the width of the `p` tag, and is completely cross browser.

Comment: The link to the fiddle makes it easy to see the results, but this would be a lot better answer if you included the CSS (and perhaps repeat the HTML) in the answer itself.

Comment: Many thanks, this works great. However when some vertical scrolling happens: then the vertical position of the text is erratic after scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

This would mean you would have to move up the DOM tree, as you want the image to determine it's parent width. **Moving up the DOM tree is unfortunately not possible** (yet).

As an alternative, you could **position the text absolute**, to lift it out of the document flow, and therefore not influence the width of it's parent div. This however would also mean that **the height does not get influenced**, which is probably not what you are after. You could mimic the correct height by repeating the parent background, but the **content underneath would not get pushed down**, so that is also not really an option I think. I set up an example anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/y8Qnd/2/

The only option I can think of is javascript. Get the width of the image and apply it to the parent container. In jQuery (I will probably get bashed for using jQuery for such a trivial thing, but I am just not used to writing 'old school javascript' anymore...) it would look something like this:

```
var $wrapper = $('div');  // you will probabaly want to use some id or class here
var width = $wrapper.find('img').width();
$wrapper.css('width', width);
```

and an example: http://jsfiddle.net/y8Qnd/6/